# keep original xml declaration when editing with python

Tags: python, xml

my original xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo/>
```

and I want to change it to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar>confusing dev</bar>
</foo>
```

I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree` as suggested by this [tutorial](http://www.diveintopython3.net/xml.html)

```
with open('file.xml','r+b') as f:
    tree = etree.parse(f)
    f.seek(0,0)
    tree.write(f,xml_declaration=True)# default argument: encoding="us-ascii"
```

this outputs

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<foo/>
```

But how do I get the encoding of `file.xml` at runtime and pass it as an argument to `tree.write` or is there a better way to edit xml in python? I just want to change some `Element.text` but keep the declaration and namespace unchanged.

Comment: Keeping form (as opposed to document semantics) truly unchanged requires an XML library written specifically for the purpose; those are very rare, because it's a lot of extra work without much benefit. You're asking much more than just preserving the encoding -- would that more restricted purpose suffice?

Comment: ...I mean, someone who *really* wanted to keep formatting identical would also ensure that `<foo bar="baz" />` doesn't get replaced with `<foo bar="baz"/>` (note the difference in whether there's a space after the attribute), capture ordering between attributes (something which has no change on document semantics), etc etc. Round-tripping is hard, and part of the goal of having a standard that provides a thorough description of the object model a document is parsed into is having clear understanding of which changes have semantic meaning and which don't.

Comment: ...being able to disregard meaningless changes is one of the advantages of that model. (Not to say that the encoding is meaningless, but you're asking for more than just encoding, whereas I'm trying to encourage you to narrow the question).

Comment: If you want the encoding to be UTF-8, then pass `encoding='utf-8'` to the `tree.write` call. If you don't write an xml declaration, version 1.0 and utf-8 encoding are the defaults; well-written XML consumers shouldn't need them to be explicitly stated.